# How can I get Perl DBI's selectrow_hashref to return a new row each iteration?

Tags: perl, dbi

I am trying to use DBI's `selectrow_hashref` instead of `fetchrow_hashref` in order to save a couple lines of code, but it keeps returning the same row of data over and over.

```
my $select="SELECT * FROM table";
while (my ($user_ref) = $dbh->selectrow_hashref()) {
    # $user_ref is the same each time!
}
```

When I use `fetchrow_hashref`, everything is fine, and each iteration I get new data.

```
my $select="SELECT * FROM table";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($select) || die "prepare: $select: $DBI::errstr";
$sth->execute() || die "execute: $select: $DBI::errstr";
while (my ($user_ref) = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    # works great, new data in $user_ref each iteration
}
```

Pray tell, what am I doing wrong? Is `selectrow_hashref` only intended to retrieve a single record?  It doesn't seem that way [in the doc](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.637/DBI.pm#selectrow_hashref).

Comment: From your link to the docs, "It returns the first row of data from the statement."

Comment: In addition, I wouldn't avoid use of the `prepare` method for any statement that will be repeatedly called.  `selectrow` is better used for one-off satements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is `selectrow_hashref` only intended to retrieve a single record?

Yes.

> It doesn't seem that way [in the doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectrow_hashref).

Well, that documentation says:

> It returns the first row of data from the statement.

Which seems pretty clear to me.

Are you looking for [`selectall_hashref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectall_hashref) instead?

**Update:** Actually, I think you want [`selectall_array`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectall_array):

```
my $select='SELECT * FROM table';
foreach my $user_ref ($dbh->selectall_array($select, { Slice => {} })) {
    # $user_ref is a hash ref
    say $user_ref->{some_column};
}
```

Comment: I had fooled myself into thinking that any of these DBI calls could be used in either single-record mode, or multi-record with "while".  Used things like `fetchrow_array` for years in both modes.  I think not knowing the internals related to "prepare" led me to wrong assumptions.  Help much appreciated!  `selectall_array` will be my new jam.